# bit-wise negation in systemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In the code below, I was expecting "b" to be `2'b00` since "a" has fewer bits than "b" and they are unsigned `wire`. However, in the simulating result, "b" is `2'b10`.

```
  wire      a;
  wire [1:0]b;

  assign a = 1'b1;
  assign b = ~a;
```

I have tried to set "b" to width 3, and this time "b" is `3'b110`.

```
  wire      a;
  wire [2:0]b;

  assign a = 1'b1;
  assign b = ~a;
```

At my understanding, if RHS has fewer bits than LHS, the unused bits of the LHS should be 0s. Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1st case, `a` is 1 bit wide, but the LHS (`b`) is 2 bits wide.  The assignment to `b` forces all values to be the maximum width (2).  Before the bitwise negation, `a` is left-extended with 0's, becoming `2'b01`.  And, `~(2'b01)` is `2'b10`.

The same is true when `b` is 3 bits wide.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.6.2 *Example of expression bit-length problem*.